# What UIKit control is being subclassed in a User Group Search/Composer? (iMessage, social media group chat)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am building a group chat system, where users on my platform can create a group to communicate with each other privately

We wanted to build our own control that is like how all the other platforms do it:

- There is a search field, it moves to the right of the "User Pills"
- Tapping on a user in a table beneath will add a "User Pill"
- "User Pills" will wrap into a new row
- You can select a "User Pill", and delete it

So my question is, does this have to be a completely custom `UIControl`, or should I consider subclassing something like `UIStackView`?

I don't mind doing the grunt work here, but I just want to make sure I'm spending my time effectively

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Personally I would use a UICollectionView